# EmberJS: Some errors not thrown in production

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Recently I encountered a scenario where an error (`Assertion Failed: calling set on destroyed object`) was thrown while running my app in development mode, but the same error wasn't thrown in production.

Why is it so? Is there a justification? 
If I'm missing, what other differences between production and development mode should I know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Assertions are removed from production builds](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.5/functions/@ember%2Fdebug/assert). All "assertion failed" errors should be addressed during development. Also production builds are usually minified and fingerprinted.

Comment: it should be noted that this is to improve performance in production.